# How to check whether a record already exists or not via Select command of dataset in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to tweak the below code for checking whether a record exist or not in the database.

```
    private bool IsAlreadyExist(string LicenseType, int JurisdictionId)
    {
        LicenceBL lbl = new LicenceBL(0);
        DataSet lds = new DataSet();
        lbl.FetchForEdit(lds, AgentId, BrokerId);
        if (lds.Tables[0].Select('LicenseType='+LicenseType+'and Jurisdiction='+JurisdictionId).Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It is not working. It throws error... Please help me !!!

Comment: What exception you getting ?

Comment: Error 22 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Comment: Add bracket to `Count`. i.e. `.Count()`

Comment: This question should be closed as it is a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nida, try this:

**(1)**

```
if (lds.Tables[0].Select('LicenseType='+LicenseType+'and Jurisdiction='+JurisdictionId).Length > 0) {

}
```

**(2)**

**LINQ**

```
int count = lds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
.Where(x => x["LicenseType"] == YourValue && y => y["Jurisdiction"]==YourValue).ToList().Count;

if (count >0) { // do your stuff}
```

Comment: Count? Really? Am I need to count all 100500 records to detect, if any exists?

Comment: For the 1st approach, if you want to avoid LINQ, maybe you should change to `Length`.  As `DataTable.Select` will return `DataRow[]`, the better option is `Length`.  For second one, I think you should use `any` instead of count, more straightforward.

Comment: Backs & Alex, thanks for pointing to improvements, answer updated.

Comment: @Backs, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I just curious the original one with `Count` can be consider as correct answer, more readable than `Where().ToList().Count()`.  Which the [`Count(TSource, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a number that represents how many elements in the specified sequence satisfy a condition.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` returns an array of rows and `Count` comes from `Linq`. So you need to call it as a method `Count()` not as a property.

```
if (lds.Tables[0].Select('LicenseType='+LicenseType+
      'and Jurisdiction='+JurisdictionId).Count() > 0)
{
```

Also instead of `if/else`, following statement, is sufficient:

```
return lds.Tables[0].Select('LicenseType='+LicenseType+
      'and Jurisdiction='+JurisdictionId).Count() > 0;
```